# Specify default string type from the Quasi quoter

Tags: haskell

I want to use `PyF` library. It has a formatter `fmt`:

```hs
-- | Generic formatter, can format an expression to any @t@ as long as
--   @t@ is an instance of 'IsString'.
fmt :: QuasiQuoter
fmt = mkFormatter "fmt" fmtConfig
```

from https://hackage.haskell.org/package/PyF-0.10.2.0/docs/src/PyF.html#fmt.

But I am trying to use it with a logging library which gets any string-like objects. And `fmt` returns `IsString`. So, to mix them together I need to specify the type - `::String` for example.

```hs
$(debug) "mylogger" ([fmt|Make a socket: port={port} ...|]::String)
```

But I don't want to do it. Is it possible to write own `fmt'` version that will return always lets say `String`? Something like

```hs
fmt' = .... fmt ....
```

How will it look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some other [relevant definitions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/PyF-0.10.2.0/docs/src/PyF.html#strConfig) from `PyF`:

```
-- | If 'OverloadedStrings' is enabled, from the input expression with
-- 'fromString'.
wrapFromString :: ExpQ -> Q Exp
wrapFromString e = do
  exts <- extsEnabled
  if OverloadedStrings `elem` exts
    then [|fromString $(e)|]
    else e

-- | Configuration for 'str' it just wrap the multiline string with 'fromString'.
strConfig :: Config
strConfig =
  Config
    { delimiters = Nothing,
      postProcess = wrapFromString
    }

-- | The config for 'fmt'.
fmtConfig :: Config
fmtConfig = addFormatting ('{', '}') strConfig
```

Here it is `wrapFromString`  which explicitly uses `fromString` to convert the expression of type `String` to `IsString s => s`. It only does so if the OverloadedStrings extension is enabled, so you could just disable that. If you want to use OverloadedStrings but also have the format string always have type `String`, you can define

```
fmt' = mkFormatter "fmt" (addFormatting ('{', '}') myConfig) where
  myConfig = Config
    { delimiters = Nothing,
      postProcess = id // note: simply removed `wrapFromString' here
    }
```

Comment: I believe `id` should work, it seems the type is `Q Exp -> Q Exp` (with `ExpQ  = Q Exp`)

Comment: Oh right. My mistake, sorry!